# Doctrine of balancing the relative conveniences of the parties

Tags: legal-terms, florida, hoa

A defense claim of *Equitable Estoppel* is invoked:

> ...Claims are barred in part of by the Doctrine of Equitable
> Estoppel...enforcing the Governing Documents as alleged by Petitioners
> would be oppressive and unreasonable.  Furthermore Petitioner's claims
> are barred by the **doctrine of balancing the relative convenience of
> the Parties**

Despite Googling the matter, a simple explanation of the bolded notion is sought:

- examples are helpful
- links are appreciated

Although IANAL, an explanation at a STEM Bachelor's degree level is appreciated.

Comment: More context would help. What is the nature of the dispute?

Comment: What is the source of the quoted language, please? Do not in future quote a source or document without properly attribution it, and provide a link whenever possible, for additional context. But in any case identify the source.

Answer (score 1):

The [Law Dictionary](https://thelawdictionary.org/balance-of-convenience/) defines the Balance of Convenience as:

> to balance the relief given to the plaintiff against the injury that will be done to the defendant.

And gives this hypothetical example:

> The court weighed the balance of convenience and opted not to grant the injunction requested by the plaintiff in light of the harm it would do to the defendant.